# Bootstrap 3 - Centered Nav and image behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this image: 
[image]

So far I have Centred by NAV bar by doing this:

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #343434;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #343434;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color: #343434;
}


hr {
    max-width: 50px;
    border-color: #4c8c8c;
    border-width: 3px;
}

hr.light {
    border-color: #fff;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-primary {
    border: 1px solid #4c8c8c;
    color: #4c8c8c;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus {
    border: 1px solid #4c8c8c;
    outline: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4c8c8c;
}

/* Preloader 
==============================================================*/
#preloader {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#fff; /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
    z-index:99; /* makes sure it stays on top */
}

#status {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
    top:50%; /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
    background-image:url(../img/status.gif); /* path to your loading animation */
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    margin:-100px 0 0 -100px; /* is width and height divided by two */
}

/* Top Banner (Above Navbar where logo sits) 
==============================================================*/
.banner {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.banner img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

/* Global Navbar Formatting
==============================================================*/
.navbar.transparent.navbar-default .navbar-inner {
    border-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop( 0% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)),color-stop( 100% , rgba(0,0,0,0.00)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.00) 100%);
}

.navbar-default {
    font-family: 'Yantramanav', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
    background-color: #fff
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #999999
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: #000
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #000
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
#topnavbar {
    margin: 0;
}
#topnavbar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <section class="banner" id="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <img src="#">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<!-- Navigation
===================================================================================-->
    <nav class="navbar transparent navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="MainNav">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">          
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">The Company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="training.html">Training & Courses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="stratagy.html">The Stratagy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I have added the banner so that I can add the logo behind, Now I Just need to get and image behind and make the nav bar static and transparent which is why im here, Could someone show me how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance, any help appreciated 
Tom

Comment: you can use `position absolute` to the image and make it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need very little the same effect as the photo you provided:

The only needed CSS for the image is just below > and you can remove the container/column/row that surrounds it. Hope ih

```
.banner {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
.banner img {
    height: 100px;
}
```

```css
/*********ADJUSTED BODY RULES*********/

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Yantramanav', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #343434;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%), url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Sydney_bridge.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'Yantramanav', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #343434;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #343434;
}
hr {
  max-width: 50px;
  border-color: #4c8c8c;
  border-width: 3px;
}
hr.light {
  border-color: #fff;
}
.btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-primary {
  border: 1px solid #4c8c8c;
  color: #4c8c8c;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus {
  border: 1px solid #4c8c8c;
  outline: 0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4c8c8c;
}
/* Preloader 
==============================================================*/

#preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* change if the mask should have another color then white */
  z-index: 99;
  /* makes sure it stays on top */
}
#status {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  /* centers the loading animation horizontally one the screen */
  top: 50%;
  /* centers the loading animation vertically one the screen */
  background-image: url(../img/status.gif);
  /* path to your loading animation */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -100px;
  /* is width and height divided by two */
}
/* Top Banner (Above Navbar where logo sits) 
==============================================================*/

/*********ADJUSTED RULES*********/

.banner {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
.banner img {
  height: 100px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
/* Global Navbar Formatting
==============================================================*/

.navbar.transparent.navbar-default {
  border-width: 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50.00% 0.00%, 50.00% 100.00%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 100%);
}
.navbar-default {
  font-family: 'Yantramanav', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #999;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #999;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#topnavbar {
  margin: 0;
}
#topnavbar.affix {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="banner" id="banner">
  <img src="http://scottace.com/img/css3-icon.png">
</section>
<!-- Navigation===================================================================================-->
<nav class="navbar transparent navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" id="MainNav">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">The Company</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="services.html">Our Services</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="training.html">Training & Courses</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="stratagy.html">The Stratagy</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: @vanburenxThis works perfectly for the Image and logo... Do you know how I can make the navbar transparent

Comment: The navbar is transparent in my example, only the active class has a background color.

Comment: Oh yes, Sorry didn't copy the whole thing, Upvoted and marked correct thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

set z-index property of image to minus value so that centered nav will come forward.

Comment: after doing this , my navbar now sits at the top of the page which I don't want,

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a image tag for this, since the background is not content relvant, try using a `background-image`. You can simply add this to your banner and position it on the bottom right.

```
background: #ccc url("your/image/path.png") no-repeat scroll right bottom;
```

Comment: When i add this to my CSS for the banner the image wont appear

Comment: You're probably using the wrong path. Use it absolute from the root, or relative from the loaded css